# PyInstaller on Linux (Ubuntu) -- open executable in console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pyinstaller

Running PyInstaller v3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04, is it possible to get my bundled application to open a console for stdout? On Mac and Windows I can get this to work, as outlined in the [options documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options). But nothing is mentioned for Linux. I've tried playing around with the `-c` flag, but that does not seem to have any effect. I also tried bundling it as a single file (`-F`) versus a directory, but neither seems to open a console for stdout...

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, in Linux if you run a bundled app from the command line like a script, it will automatically use that same terminal as `stdout` ...